# Install tflearn using pip3 on ubuntu correctly

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, tflearn

I have seen lot of answers regarding installation on tflearn using pip but none have helped me. I am using python3 and tensorflow (1.0.0), tensorflow-tensorboard (1.5.0) and tflearn (0.3.2). If I install tflearn it says "cant import tflearn it isn't installed" or something like that but then I uninstalled it and again installed several times using:-

```
 sudo pip3 install tflearn
```

Also tried:-

```
 sudo pip install tflearn
```

I can see tflearn using both:-

```
  pip list
```

and:-

```
 pip3 list
```

And if I try to install it without sudo it says that permission not granted. How can I properly set up tflearn on ubuntu 16.04 using pip3, please someone tell me cause I have been scratching head for this thing from past 3 days.
My pip/pip3 are working fine for other packages only tflearn is causing issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change your installation command slightly.

`sudo python3.6 -m pip install tflearn` worked for me.

Obviously you will need tenseflow installed as well.

Comment: It worked for me, you are a life saviour. I have tensorflow, thanks.

Comment: @AsimRaja  It's a deceiving command, it may look like it's starting the python interpreter, but yes it's actually activating pip.I recommend you try install like this when you have pip errors in future, it just seems to be more likely to work.

Comment: Oh okay got it.